# Can you use Shrink Item on a living creature?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Are you allowed to use the spell *Shrink Item* on a living creature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Nope!**

Shrink Item is specifically designed for an object, for which creatures do not qualify. You're wanting either Reduce Person or Reduce Creature.

Or Reduce Animal, as the case might be.
http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/lists/spells&tablefilter=reduce

Answer (score 5):

The spell specifically mentions a non-living object so no....but you COULD kill them and shrink their body (if you needed to hide a corpse somewhere but with a lack of space).

Comment: I like your line of thinking.

Comment: Once a friend of mine tried to pull off some wild trick involving persisting Shrink Item on his corpse while using a magic jar or asking someone to resurrect him.